# Connect to twitter API using SSL in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, twitter

I'm trying to get the user's Twitter timeline using the Twitter API in iOS SDK and got an error saying:

`code = 92;    message = "SSL is required";`

I googled the error and I found [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl) on the Twitter API website, but I have no idea how to use it in iOS.

Here's my code:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {


     if (granted == YES){

         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];


         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {

             ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject]; 

             NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"]; 


             NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

             [parameters setObject:@"100" forKey:@"count"];

             [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];



             SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];

             posts.account = twitterAccount;



             [posts performRequestWithHandler:

              ^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse
                *urlResponse, NSError *error)
              {
                  // The NSJSONSerialization class is then used to parse the data returned and assign it to our array.

                  array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                  if (array.count != 0) {

                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          NSLog(@"%@",array);
                      });

                  }

              }];

         }

     } else {

         // Handle failure to get account access
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

     }

 }];
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "https" in your URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline